# SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(filename) replacing empty value with 0 in excel file

Tags: c#, devexpress, export-to-excel, spreadsheetgear

I have DevEx gridControl with some data from DB.

```
gridControl.ExportToXlsx(filename, new XlsxExportOptions(TextExportMode.Value));
```

this code block Works fine and export data to excel. after export, I am opening and closing excel file using SpreadsheetGear like below...

```
WorkBook = Factory.GetWorkbook(filename);
WorkBook.Save();
WorkBook.Close();
```

My intention is to perform some task after opening excel file but This opening and closing of excel file replacing all empty values in excel file with 0 (zero).

Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening and how can I fix this.

one more point to add, if I export data with `TextExportMode.Text` option then SpreadsheetGear is not replacing empty values with 0 but exporting as Text will not solve my purpose.

Thanks in advance.